# The controller with the name 'StaticPageController' is not registered ocLazyLoading + routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, oclazyload

I've been tring to use ocLazyLoad but this works fine when controller file is cached. I mean for the first visit it gives me controller undefined error but when I visit second time it works fine. Please help

```
      (function() {
      'use strict';

      angular
        .module('abc.config', ['ui.router', 'ngRoute', 'oc.lazyLoad'])
        .config(config);
      config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
      function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/contact-us', {
            templateUrl: 'app/staticPages/contact-us.html',
            controller: 'StaticPageController',
            controllerAs: 'StaticController',
            resolve: { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
              loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                // you can lazy load files for an existing module
                return $ocLazyLoad.load('app/staticPages/static.controller.js');
              }]
            }
          })
          .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/404'
          });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
      }
    })();
```

Controller.js

```
 (function() {
      'use strict';

  angular
    .module('abc')
    .controller('StaticPageController', StaticPageController);
  StaticPageController.$inject = [];
  function StaticPageController() {

  }
})();
```

I hope this controller file may hilep you debug my problem.

Comment: update your question with controller file.

Comment: @RaviKumar Updated. Please have a look. Thanks for all your help

Comment: not sure but try adding angular.module('abc.config') instead angular.module('abc')

Comment: Why do you have both `ui.router` and `ngRoute` as dependencies? Seems like that could be a problem.

Comment: I'm converting my Angular APP from ui.router to ngRoute because ui.router is created unnecessary errors. i.e. $animLeave is undefined. I explored this and it's an ui-router issue which doesn't seems to be fixing anymore but that s another topic.